# Haskell monad return arbitrary data type

Tags: haskell, return, monads

I am having trouble defining the return over a custom defined recursive data type.

The data type is as follows:

data A a = B a | C (A a) (A a)

However, I don't know how to define the return statement since I can't figure out when to return B value and when to recursively return C.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is a binary tree, you could have a look at the [Monad instance for `Data.Tree.Tree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Tree.html#line-71) and see if you can adapt it.

Comment: You can provide any definition you want as long as it serves your purposes and obeys [the Monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to define a `Monad` instance for this type is to treat it as a *free* monad. In effect, this takes `A a` to be a little syntax with one binary operator `C`, and variables represented by values of type `a` embedded by the `B` constructor. That makes `return` the `B` constructor, embedding variables, and `>>=` the operator which performs subsitution.

```
instance Monad A where
  return = B
  B x   >>= f = f x
  C l r >>= f = C (l >>= f) (r >>= f)
```

It's not hard to see that `(>>= B)` performs the identity substitution, and that composition of substitutions is associative.

Another, more "imperative" way to see this monad is that it captures the idea of computations that can flip coins (or read a bitstream or otherwise have some access to a sequence of binary choices).

```
data Coin = Heads | Tails
```

Any computation which can flip coins must either stop flipping and be a value (with `B`), or flip a coin and carry on (with `C`) in one way if the coin comes up `Heads` and another if `Tails`. The monadic operation which flips a coin and tells you what came up is

```
coin :: A Coin
coin = C (B Heads) (B Tails)
```

The `>>=` of `A` can now be seen as sequencing coin-flipping computations, allowing the choice of a subsequent computation to depend on the value delivered by an earlier computation.

If you have an infinite stream of coins, then (apart from your extraordinary good fortune) you're also lucky enough to be able to run any `A`-computation to its value, as follows

```
data Stream x = x :> Stream x   -- actually, I mean "codata"

flipping :: Stream Coin -> A v -> v
flipping _             (B v)    = v
flipping (Heads :> cs) (C h t)  = flipping cs h
flipping (Tails :> cs) (C h t)  = flipping cs t
```

The general pattern in this sort of monad is to have one constructor for returning a value (`B` here) and a bunch of others which represent the choice of possible operations and the different ways computations can continue given the result of an operation. Here `C` has no non-recursive parameters and two subtrees, so I could tell that there must be just one operation and that it must have just two possible outcomes, hence flipping a coin.

So, it's substitution for a syntax with variables and one binary operator, or it's a way of sequencing computations that flip coins. Which view is better? Well... they're two sides of the same coin.

Comment: Thanks! The bind function is actually very similar to what we had before, but we had a conceptual error, and it fixed it :]

Comment: Finally, a free monad answer I didn't have to give.

Answer (score 7):

A good rule of thumb for `return` is to make it the simplest possible thing which could work (of course, any definition that satisfies the monad laws is fine, but usually you want something with minimal structure). In this case it's as simple as `return = B` (now write a `(>>=)` to match!).

By the way, this is an example of a [free monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Free.html) -- in fact, it's the example given in the documentation, so I'll let the documentation speak for itself.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I definitely misunderstood how to properly override Monad functions.